# RTTI Overhead in C++

Tags: c++, casting, rtti

What are the memory/performance overheads of enabling RTTI in a C++ program?
Can anyone please throw some light between the internal implementation of RTTI mechanism and the relevant overheads?
I do understand how to use RTTI through `typeid` and `dynamic_cast`, what I am trying to know is the internal implementation details of how the run time keeps track of this information and how it is an overhead?

Comment: If you need the functionality of dynamic_cast, it is not an overhead. How else would you do it "cheaper"?

Comment: @Bo Persson: The question is not because i know or there is/would be a way of doing it "cheaper" but the question is to understand how the internal RTTI implementation is and to be informed about what it's apparent overheads are. I think it's natural to be inquisitive about whats happening behind the scenes when we are using certain aspects of a programing language.

Comment: I'm just arguing against you calling it overhead. If it is a functionality you need, it is not overhead. :-) If you don't need it, don't use it.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Agreed on the overhead point! Probably I should say "Cost" rather than "Overhead" :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Enabling RTTI typically brings only a small overhead. The usual implementation carries a pointer to the type information structure in the vtable of an object. Since the vtable must be constructed anyway, the extra time is small - it's like adding another virtual function to the class.

`typeid` is therefore comparable to calling a virtual function.
`dynamic_cast` is slower - it needs to traverse the inheritance hierarchy to do a cast. Calling `dynamic_cast` too frequently *can* be a performance bottleneck. By '*can*' I mean that it usually won't …

There is a slight bloat in executable size since the typeinfo structures need to be stored somewhere. In most cases it won't be relevant.

Comment: As Bo Persson commented, it is important to note that if you want `typeid` and `dynamic_cast` this isn't overhead: it is required to implement the functionality. Also, since VTables tend to be constant structures with just a pointer assigned at runtime, there is probably zero overhead.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer best sums up the "overhead" or rather "cost" of RTTI.

Answer (score 11):

Please read appropriate section in [this document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/TR18015.pdf).

To sum up:

- `typeid` (5.3.7): find vtable, through that find most derived class object, then extract type_info from that object's vtable. It is still very slow comparing with function call;
- `dynamic_cast` (5.3.8): find type_info as described above, then determine whether conversion is possible, then adjust pointers. Run-time cost depends on the relative position in the class hierarchy of two classes involved. Down- and cross-casts are very slow these days (though [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/fast_dynamic_casting.pdf) you can find the article about possible (but restricted) constant-time implementation of dynamic_cast).

Comment: You are cordially invited to sum up "the appropriate section" in your answer. This way, if the link goes dead, your answer won't end up worthless.

Comment: Yes, sir! (Though docs of standardization committee rarely go dead)

Comment: The TR actually says "very slow compared to a _function call_", not  " virtual function call".

Comment: Either way the answer still says "with a function call" and not "to a"

Comment: I realize this post is more than 10 years old, and the referred to document even older, but the description of typeid doesn't make a whole lot of sense. The vtable can (and in practice will) already contain a reference to the typeinfo object of the most derived type, because the actual vtable belongs that most derived type. We don't need to "find" it. It can basically be just 2 levels of indirection: object -> vtable -> typeinfo. Compiler Explorer output reflects that: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/a6qdMjd1q. Anything more complicated is an implementation choice, not an inherent feature cost

Answer (score 1):

First there is no way to say exactly how much overhead is involved with out specifying a compiler and version  as it is an implementation detail.  That said it is well known that in some compilers dynamic_cast searches the class hierarchy doing string comparisons to match class names.

Answer (score -5):

I wonder where did get the idea of RTTI "overhead" ?

I read on the net, that in order to provide R.T.T.I., some (early) C to C++ preprocessors or translators, similar tools (GObject, QT, Objective-C, not sure), and other progr. langr. generate some "behind the scene" code, that did generate some "overhead" in memory and speed.

I read that eventually, that "overhead" was reduced and many times is considered trivial.

Maybe you would like to program in assembly, or "plain C", without R.T.T.I. overhead, is much easier than C++

Comment: From Wikipedia: "In engineering, some methods or components make special demands on the system. The extra design features necessary to accommodate these demands are called overhead.". The question was "What are the memory/performance overheads of enabling RTTI in a C++ program?". Relevant to say the least.