# How to implement CView::OnUpdate in derived view class

Tags: c++, mfc

3rd parameter of `OnUpdate` is a pointer to `CObject`. The pointer must be downcasted in the view class that implements its own `OnUpdate`. What is the best way to check if the cast succeed? Use `CObject::IsKindOf` or `dynamic_cast`? Is it OK to use RTTI in MFC projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created your view using the wizards, then it will have put a DECLARE_DYNCREATE in the header file of your view class. If you created it by hand, I would make sure it has a DECLARE_DYNCREATE in the class definition of your view's header file (or at least a DECLARE_DYNAMIC or DECLARE_SERIAL--DECLARE_SERIAL is generally overkill for a view class).

THen, when you want to downcast use the DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST macro and test for not NULL on return.

CView* pView = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CView, pObject); // is one usage

Don't listen to advice to not use the MFC macro because it's not portable... If you're writing a CView derived class, it's already not portable--unless you use a toolkit like Wind/U, and then DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST will be portable as well.

Answer (score 0):

`CObject::IsKindOf()` will work only if class is declared with `DECLARE_DYNAMIC`,  `DECLARE_DYNCREATE`, or `DECLARE_SERIAL` (`CView` declares them) but don't require RTTI support.

While `dynamic_cast` works with RTTI support, it contains some overhead and executable size is increased slightly, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408106/rtti-overhead-in-c)..

Answer (score 0):

I use dynamic_cast in my job and have no problems.
Checking cast success is very easy:
CDerivedView* pView = dynamic_cast(pViewObj);
if (! pView) { ASSERT(0); return; }

Also, we try to not use MFC's macro, because they are unportable - such as MFC itself, although.
I think, good program mustn't hardly depend on libraries it has been used.