# Why C++ does not use centralized storage for type information for efficient RTTI?

Tags: c++

As far as I know each polymorphic class in C++ contains a string with a mangled type name. And RTTI is implemented by string comparison.

Is this true? Would it be more efficient to implement a centralized type storage instead?

With centralized type storage each object can just hold a pointer to type information. Dynamic casts can be implemented simply by pointer comparison.

Comment: Related question: [RTTI overhead in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408106/rtti-overhead-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual implementation is even more efficient than one pointer per object.

The Standard forbids adding any data to "standard layout" classes, so there's not even room for a pointer, let alone a string.  For polymorphic classes, there will be extra metadata, but in real-world implementations, all data specific to the dynamic type of the object is stored together, and there's just one pointer needed to all of it.

As a result, because polymorphic objects already need a pointer to the virtual function dispatch table, there is zero incremental per-object cost to storing the type name.  There just an extra pointer stored in the v-table alongside the function pointers, so the cost is one pointer per polymorphic type no matter how many instances exist.

Comment: Does this mean that that two objects of same type will share metadata? Why then dynamic_cast is considered slow in C++ world?

Comment: @random: `dynamic_cast` is slow because it can move between any two types in the inheritance tree of the object's dynamic type.  It is NOT the same as an equality check on `typeid`  There can be multiple base classes (multiple inheritance or indirect inheritance or a mixture), with multiple different access modifiers, and then there is virtual inheritance.  There's quite a bit of data to inspect to not only find out whether the cast is legal, but to calculate the address of the requested subobject.

Comment: Interesting. Why can't compiler calculate offset of requested object? Like it does for static_cast?

Comment: @random: Because the offset differs depending on the object passed in.  Consider at least two cases: cross-casts and virtual inheritance.

Comment: @random: "*Why can't compiler calculate offset of requested object? Like it does for static_cast?*" The whole point of a dynamic cast is that it is *dynamic*. Specifically, that it can *fail*. If you cast from a `T*` to a `U*`, but the specific `T` object in question isn't actually a `U`, `dynamic_cast` will return `nullptr`. `static_cast` will happily compute an offset that points to an object that *does not exist*.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The potential for failure is NOT why the offset cannot be calculated at compile time.  For all casts where `static_cast` would be well-formed, `dynamic_cast` will verify the runtime type and then if successful, add exactly the same offset, computed at compile-time, as `static_cast` would have.  It is the additional cases, supported by `dynamic_cast` where a `static_cast` would be ill-formed, where the offset must be dynamically computed.  Of course, even a `static_cast` has a runtime check within the offset calculation, namely `if (p == nullptr) offset = 0; else ` ...

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphic classes contain what the compiler builder considered worthy putting in them, there is no rule or requirement to have any type information.
The concept of C++ is strongly typed, and the checking id to be done by the compiler. The compiled code is typically optimized for performance and/or size, and not to carry information that shouldn’t be needed.

Of course, some compilers offer this, but that is not the spirit of the language.

Comment: "polymorphic" applies to those types, and only those types, where type checking cannot be completed at compile time in all contexts.  It starts then, but has runtime logic as well.